# How to get a message for editing Discord .NET

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am doing a command for my bot to edit a message sent by it
But I need to get the message to edit it
I found a function that obtains it but returns an `IMessage` which does not have the `ModifyAsync()` function
This is my code:

```
[Command("editmessage")]
public async Task EditMessage(string sMessageId, string TextMessage) {

     ulong MessageId = Convert.ToUInt64(sMessageId);
     var Message = Context.Channel.GetMessageAsync(MessageId);
     
     await Message.ModifyAsync(msg => msg.Content = TextMessage); //This gives me an error because "IMessage" does not contain a definition for "ModifyAsync"

}
```

Is there a way to go from `IMessage` to `IUserMessage`? (`IUserMessage` if it has the `ModifyAsync()` function)

Forgive me for my bad english

Comment: You can force a conversion, note that it will fail if the underlying type is not a `IUserMessage`. You could do `Message as IUserMessage` to convert.

Comment: I just tried it, and it works perfectly for me, thank you very much

Comment: You're right, when I run the command it gives me an error in ```await Message.ModifyAsync(msg => msg.Content = TextMessage);```

Comment: I was checking and when I convert, it becomes null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is `await` for the operation to complete asynchronously via `await`. Don't use `.Result` here as that is a blocking operation.

```
[Command("editmessage")]
public async Task EditMessage(string messageId, string textMessage) 
{
     var id = Convert.ToUInt64(messageId);
     var msg = await Context.Channel.GetMessageAsync(id);

     if ( msg is IUserMessage message )
     {
         await message.ModifyAsync(m => m.Content = textMessage);
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Taking into account what I have been told, I did tests I found this solution:

```
[Command("editmessage")]
public async Task EditMessage(string sMessageId, string TextMessage) {

     ulong MessageId = Convert.ToUInt64(sMessageId);
     var _Message = Context.Channel.GetMessageAsync(MessageId).Result; //It is important to put the `.Result`

     var Message = _Message as IUserMessage;

     await Message.ModifyAsync(msg => msg.Content = TextMessage);

}
```

Comment: *Don't do that*, you're waiting for the functions return `synchronously`

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand.
Please could you be more specific in what I shouldn't do?

Comment: using `Result` means, "block the executing thread until I have received a result". Instead use `await`.  For example: `var _Message = await Context.Channel.GetMessageAsync(MessageId);`

Comment: With `.Result`, you potentially block the thread in Discord.NET that handles other tasks, like sending pings to keep the connection alive or updating caches. With `await`, you give Discord.NET the chance to control what gets blocked and what does not.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, i have it more clear now